# Creating automatic disk snapshot (backup) retention on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-console

I'd like to know if there is a way to create an automatic backup retention for an instance (disk more specifically). I'm not very experienced with the console so I prefer a GUI way, but if there is no I'll be glad to know about the console method.

I was looking for this but only found a solution for SQL.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

The script has changed a lot since I first gave this answer - please see Github repo for latest code: https://github.com/jacksegal/google-compute-snapshot

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

I had the same problem, so I created a simple shell script to take a daily snapshot and delete all snapshots over 7 days: https://github.com/jacksegal/google-compute-snapshot

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/:/usr/bin

#
# CREATE DAILY SNAPSHOT
#

# get the device name for this vm
DEVICE_NAME="$(curl -s "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/disks/0/device-name" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google")"

# get the device id for this vm
DEVICE_ID="$(curl -s "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/id" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google")"

# get the zone that this vm is in
INSTANCE_ZONE="$(curl -s "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/zone" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google")"

# strip out the zone from the full URI that google returns
INSTANCE_ZONE="${INSTANCE_ZONE##*/}"

# create a datetime stamp for filename
DATE_TIME="$(date "+%s")"

# create the snapshot
echo "$(gcloud compute disks snapshot ${DEVICE_NAME} --snapshot-names gcs-${DEVICE_NAME}-${DEVICE_ID}-${DATE_TIME} --zone ${INSTANCE_ZONE})"


#
# DELETE OLD SNAPSHOTS (OLDER THAN 7 DAYS)
#

# get a list of existing snapshots, that were created by this process (gcs-), for this vm disk (DEVICE_ID)
SNAPSHOT_LIST="$(gcloud compute snapshots list --regexp "(.*gcs-.*)|(.*-${DEVICE_ID}-.*)" --uri)"

# loop through the snapshots
echo "${SNAPSHOT_LIST}" | while read line ; do

   # get the snapshot name from full URL that google returns
   SNAPSHOT_NAME="${line##*/}"

   # get the date that the snapshot was created
   SNAPSHOT_DATETIME="$(gcloud compute snapshots describe ${SNAPSHOT_NAME} | grep "creationTimestamp" | cut -d " " -f 2 | tr -d \')"

   # format the date
   SNAPSHOT_DATETIME="$(date -d ${SNAPSHOT_DATETIME} +%Y%m%d)"

   # get the expiry date for snapshot deletion (currently 7 days)
   SNAPSHOT_EXPIRY="$(date -d "-7 days" +"%Y%m%d")"

   # check if the snapshot is older than expiry date
if [ $SNAPSHOT_EXPIRY -ge $SNAPSHOT_DATETIME ];
        then
     # delete the snapshot
         echo "$(gcloud compute snapshots delete ${SNAPSHOT_NAME} --quiet)"
   fi
done
```

Comment: How can we setup cron jobs on compute engine?

Comment: @AbdulRehman - it's the same as setting up a cron job on any other cloud provider - see these instructions: https://askubuntu.com/a/2369.  I have written instructions on how to setup a cron for this specific script on the github readme: https://github.com/jacksegal/google-compute-snapshot.

Comment: Hi, @JackSegal - I need to delete snapshots older than 10 days, so I have changed that bit of code: `echo -e "\nUsage: $0 [-d 7]" 1>&2`  that's right thing I have changed to change days interval or I need to make changes somewhere else?

Comment: @AbdulRehman - are you using the latest script from github?  If so, you can pass in the number of days you want to keep the snapshots as a parameter.  e.g.: ./snapshot.sh -d 10

Comment: The script is working now, but the cron job doesn't run at the specified time, I schedule the time to execute the script at 14:18 but it didn't run the script at the appointed time as 18 14 * * * root ..., can you help me, please!

Comment: @AbdulRehman - how are you doing the cron?  via crontab or cron.d?

Answer (score 0):

Two comments about this very useful script (if you're using the one above)

Line

> --regexp "(.*gcs-.*)|(.*-${DEVICE_ID}-.*)"

Probably has a bug ; this lists everything starting with GCS
I think it should read

> --regexp "(.*gcs-.*)-(.*-${DEVICE_ID}-.*)"

At least this is the one I'm using to output the expected result

Also, this --regexp is now deprecated, if you care about the warning, you could use

> SNAPSHOT_LIST="$(gcloud compute snapshots list  --filter="name~'(.*gcs-.*)-(.*-${DEVICE_ID}-.*)'" --uri)"

The author has a newer version  on his git , these are only comments about the above script. The regexp is rather dangerous, as, as-is, the above script basically deletes snapshots from other VMs using the same script.